# Trapped in an ocean Temple in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've found myself in a horror movie. I was exploring an ocean Temple in Minecraft, and to protect myself from Guardians, I barricaded myself in completely. However, they are still inflicting mining fatigue on me through the blocks, and they're regular enough with it that I can never run out the timer, so I cannot break blocks. I've just built myself into a tomb.

The game is on easy mode, so I can't starve to death. I don't have any milk to debuff, so I can't dig myself out. I don't have any water, so I can't drown myself. I'm trapped.

At this point, I'd be glad to die and revive back in my village, but I can't figure out how. Can anybody think of anything?

Comment: Hey Daniel. You've edited your question and title with the word "resolved" and your solution to show that your question is answered. That's normal (and greatly appreciated!) on other forums, but Stack Exchange actually has built-in methods for doing this. Could you undo your edits, and instead click the check mark icon next to to whichever answer solved your problem? That's how we usually do things round here, and it also spreads out some internet points to the people who helped you!

Comment: Additionally, if none of the answers actually solved your problem, them feel free to post an answer yourself.

Comment: In the future, us a door instead of solid blocks ;)

Comment: @goodguy5 doors on slimeblocks. Even with mining fatigue XXX a slime block breaks instantly. With four slimeblocks you can drain entire rooms. Place slimeblock on the floor, door on top. hedge, break, profit.

Comment: What did you barricade yourself in with?

Answer (score 49):

Mining fatigue only slows your mining down, it doesn't completely prevent it. So you can for example bind your mining action to a key on your keyboard instead of a mouse button and put a weight on it, then go away for a few minutes while your character slooowly breaks the block.

Comment: This would take over eight hundred million seconds, if you swim (not stand) in water, with mining fatigue 3, using your hand to mine obsidian. That's over 27 years. Not quite as much as the Doctor. Even measured in in-game moon cycles, it's "just" 6804×12 months.

Answer (score 13):

While making yourself mine a block forever isn't a bad solution, if you're looking for a much easier way to get out of this scenario, just go to your options and open to LAN with cheats enabled.

Then, you can either put yourself in creative and break a block, use `/kill @s`,  or whatever feels fair to you.

Answer (score 12):

Mining Fatigue only slows mining but at level 3 it will take a VERY long time to break any blocks. What you could do is set the world to peaceful which will make the elder guardians permanently despawn. You can do this and still get achievements and such.

Answer (score 12):

Solutions with breaking blocks possibly are the simpliest ones, but there is an another way. It is to cause Minecraft regenerate the chunk.

The chunk you're at, erases all the changes you've made in it, and returns to its initial state like it was when the world was first generated. I personally used it several times in difficult situations, and it helped me. I cause it by quitting the world, then entering it and quitting it again as fast as I can. This action will regenerate the chunk you're currently in, and so it will erase the blocks you have placed, and will let you go out of the temple.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm pretty active on the bug tracker, but I've never heard about this. Do you have a link to the report?

Comment: @FabianRöling I don't because I experienced it myself, so I am sure it exists.

Comment: @FabianRöling Here are some of these issues: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-147831 https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-147850

Comment: That was just 1.14-pre1 and had nothing to do with quickly closing after opening. The two reports you linked where closed as duplicates of the same one which says exactly that. I'm not sure why 15 people upvoted this answer, it does not work. I've opened and quickly closed worlds many times and this has never happened, in any version.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the difficulty to hard, wait until you starve, then change it back.